# What makes fruits conduct electricity?

Tags: electricity, voltage, batteries, electrochemistry

I'm sure most people are aware of the fact that certain fruits and vegetables are capable of generating electricity. But my main question is:

**1. What are the names of such fruits that conduct electricity and how much volts does each fruit generate (e.g Can such volts be used to charge a power bank, etc.)**

**2. Are there any side effects to this method, Either to the phone or charger?**

**Note: Minimum of 3, Maximum of 5 so as to reduce the broadness of the question.**

Comment: Pls, if this question is not meant to be in this stack exchange, do tell....and pls do not criticize, simply correct.

Comment: Your question #1 which talks about how many "volts does each fruit generate" shows a basic misunderstanding about how something like a potato battery or lemon battery works, and it would require a bit of time and effort here to explain how such batteries work. Suggest that you first read up on how such batteries work and then come back with any questions.

Comment: http://www.telegraph.co.uk/technology/news/10988301/How-to-charge-your-phone-with-apples-and-potatoes.html.   Charging your phone with fruit, **lots** of fruit.

Answer (score 4):

Most fruits and vegetables will conduct electricity because they contain water (with extra ions).

To generate electricity you need to stick two metal electrodes into the fruit. The metals have to be different. The (maximum) voltage produced is much more dependent on what the metals are than on which fruit is used.

Usually these fruit or vegetable batteries are not very useful. Their maximum voltage (or 'e m f'), that is the voltage between the electrodes when no 'load' is connected between them, is in the order of 1 V per cell. This is quite respectable, but the voltage falls dramatically when a load (such as an led) is connected. This is because the cell has an unacceptably high internal resistance. This in turn is partly because the fruit or vegetable juices don't have a large enough concentration of ions and/or unwanted chemical processes take place.